# Windows 11 home/ Win 10 Pro. How to prevent standard users from installing software?

Tags: windows, administrative-privileges

It seems that I cannot prevent a standard account from installing software. I tried that on windows 10 Pro and on Windows 11 home.  I have a problem similar to this [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/standard-user-account-able-to-install-programs/16681a59-b271-4499-82f8-4bf131a4981e). But the admin popup did not even show up in my case.

Editing the registry or using (Group Policy Editor) as suggested all over the internet ([Like this](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/block-users-installing-software-windows-computer/)) did not work at all. (The funny part is that Windows 11 home does not even have (Group Policy Editor).

I test it by restarting my computer and installing the Whatsapp application using **a standard account**, and it installs normally. I expected to see a popup that requires an administrator password.

Answer (score 1):

Any user can run or install in its own user profile folder without admin privilege if the application don’t invoke admin right access or write file in restriction place.

You need AppLocker or such policy, which is available in Enterprise version, or use third part tool that can do that.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/applocker-overview

Answer (score 0):

I agree with yagmoth555.
In the pro versions, where Applocker is missing, use software restriction policies. In the home version, use this frontend to get the same functionality: https://www.heise.de/download/product/restrictor
It's in german, but I think you will still understand what's what. Be careful though, not to lock yourself out.

Comment: This tool has not been updated since 2017 and according to comments is not fully compatible to Windows 11.

Comment: Gerald, SRP are registry based and there's no functional difference in Win11 SRP. The commenter suggest that system32 executables are not starting, which is not reproducible here.